# Yfinance Dividend sumation issue

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to write a simple screener searching for buy signals among Dividend Aristocrats uploaded from a .csv file. The screener ought to iterate for each ticker and upload the dividends paid in the last year period (a setting). Then it should calculate three conditions

1. the amount of dividends paid within a year x100 should be above the 4 % of the current price
2. The last price should be at least 10 % or above the last year minimum price
3. The price should be above 50 SMA

I have two issues

First issue is that my ticker iteration does not start. It only iterates the first ticker. No code alarms of any kind, it just does not do the work.

Second issue is with my  1.st condition. I can not retrieve the dividends for the defined period of time nor do any kind of sumation.

Please advise

### Thanks

## Stock Screener

```
 import pandas as pd
 import yfinance as yf
 import pandas_datareader as web
 import datetime
 from datetime import timedelta
 import numpy as np
 import talib as ta


# List of tickers
 index_to_keep = [1]
 data = pd.read_csv('/home/ata/MEGAsync/Python/DAI.csv',error_bad_lines = False, 
 engine = 'python',usecols = [0],skiprows=2)


# timeframe definition
st_dni=400                                             # one year + (can be changed)
end = datetime.date.today()                            # from today
start = end-timedelta(days=st_dni)                     # back

for ticker in data:                                    
   df = web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start, end)     # ticker data

   stock=yf.Ticker(ticker,start)                      # dividend data 
   div = stock.dividends(period='st_dni')
   sum(div)                                           # dividend (1st cond)

   dataframe = np.array(df)                           # np array conversion
   hi = np.round(dataframe[:,1])                        
   lo = np.round(dataframe[:,2])
   hl = (hi+lo)/2                                     # hi/lo values
   df_min = np.min(lo)                                # year low (2nd cond)
   
   mabig  = ta.SMA(ohlc,50)                          # SMA (3rd cond)
```

CSV file is available on [this](https://mega.nz/file/25EQGRhD#xZdRvMxxsU2Q3FS2Qs0y0resdqPNCeKs-F2meTBdar4) link

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

First issue solved with

```
...
for ticker in data: 
   ticker = data.loc[i,'SYMBOL']
...
```

Second issue solved with

```
...
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)                           
temp = pd.DataFrame(stock.dividends)
div = temp.loc[start:end]
...
```

I hope someone find this useful.